# Импорт файла CVS в базу данных. Java

Tags: java, sql, база-данных

Прошу не судить строго. Пишу код- учусь.
Существует потребность в загрузке файла формата CVS в базу данных.

Также, в задании присутствуют параметры доступа к БД:

- host
- port
- database
- schema
- целевая таблица
- login
- password

Прошу Вас объяснить как получить доступ к этой базе данных, а также привести пример кода, где реализована загрузка содержимого в БД. ЯП - Java.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Укажите точно используемую СУБД - включая версию.

Comment: Возможно, я что-то не понимаю..Первый раз работаю с БД.
Не могу ответить на Ваш вопрос. Не имею понимание какая версия вообще используется. Думал, что подключусь по параметрам и там уже будет ясно, какая там СУБД, какая версия. 
P.S. В изначальном задании это не сказано

Comment: К разным СУБД по-разному придётся подключаться. Разные библиотеки доступа, разные драйверы доступа... к тому же в задании schema и database явно неэквивалентны - что верно далеко не для каждой СУБД.

Comment: СУБД - PostgreSQL 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предельно простой пример с использованием SQLite в качестве СУБД

**Demo.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;


public class Demo {
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:test.db";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persons ("
                                                   + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                                   + "name TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                                   + "age INTEGER NOT NULL)";
    private static final String INSERT_PERSON_QUERY = "INSERT INTO persons (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL)) {
            try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
                 stmt.execute(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY);
            }
            catch (SQLException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }

            try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("test.csv"));
                 PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_PERSON_QUERY)) {
                String[] record;
                while ((record = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    stmt.setString(1, record[0]);
                    stmt.setInt(2, Integer.valueOf(record[1]));
                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
            catch(IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (SQLException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**test.csv**

```
John,30
Jack,28
Jimm,41
```

В общем-то вам нужно только заменить строку `DB_URL` на ваши параметры доступа к БД в соответствии с правилами формирования JDBC URL и обеспечить в CLASSPATH наличие необходимого драйвера СУБД.

Comment: Большое спасибо!
А как быть, если cvs-файл уже существует? (таблицу не нужно уже создавать. Она находится в этом файле). М.б. как-то сослаться на неё в коде и потом уже добавить в БД.

Comment: В примере как раз ситуация, когда "csv-файл уже существует". Таблица в БД и таблица в CSV файле - это две разных сущности. Вы не сможете что-либо записать в базу, если в ней не будет таблицы.

Comment: Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что изменится в коде, если СУБД - PostgreSQL ?

Comment: @LeilaBoord ничего. Это написано в последнем абзаце.

Comment: Спасибо. Уже разобрался.

Comment: @LeilaBoord [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).